# Alternative class provider for Http with Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am trying to use an alternative class for Http in Angular 2.

I want to do so to have a CustomHttp class setting default options in constructor

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, RequestOptions, ConnectionBackend} from 'angular2/http';

@Injectable()
export class CustomHttp extends Http {
    constructor(_backend: ConnectionBackend, _defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
        super(_backend, _defaultOptions);
        let jwtHeader = localStorage.getItem('jwt');
        if (jwtHeader != null) {
            this._defaultOptions.headers.append('Authorization', jwtHeader);
        }
        console.log("Pouet CustomHttp");
    }
}
```

I tried various options when bootstrapping, as I want this overload to be global to my app.

I tried :

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, 
    [HTTP_PROVIDERS,
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
        provide(Http, {useClass: CustomHttp,deps: [XHRBackend, BaseRequestOptions]})
    ]);
```

it raises :

```
browser_adapter.ts:73 EXCEPTION: No provider for ConnectionBackend! (TAPComponent -> SensService -> Http -> ConnectionBackend)
```

I also tried :

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, 
    [HTTP_PROVIDERS,
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
            provide(Http, {useFactory:
                function(backend, defaultOptions) {
                  return new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions);
                },
                deps: [XHRBackend, BaseRequestOptions]})
    ]);
```

it raises :

```
browser_adapter.ts:73 EXCEPTION: No provider for BaseRequestOptions! (TAPComponent -> SensService -> Http -> BaseRequestOptions)
```

What should I do ?

I am using beta 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a factory to configure it with `RequestOptions` instead of `BaseRequestOptions`:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  new Provider(Http, {
    useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) => new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions),
    deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
  })
]);
```

`HTTP_PROVIDERS` only provides `RequestOptions` not `BaseRequestOptions`.

`BaseRequestOptions` should be used if you want to define custom request options by defining a sub class of it.

Comment: Many thanks... I am so used to java CDI that I did not imagine it would not pick an implementation on his own...

Comment: You're welcome! In fact, `HTTP_PROVIDERS` only provides `RequestOptions` not `BaseRequestOptions`. Yes I understand well ;-)

Comment: is it still supported for angular2 release ?

Comment: Can confirm this works in angular 2.1.1. Just make sure your CustomHttp class has a constructor like:

`
constructor (backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) {
  super(backend, options);
}
`

Comment: I created an article for this - http://adonespitogo.com/articles/angular-2-extending-http-provider/